# Extjs-Adding seconds to timestamp

Tags: extjs

I have a form with timestamp field with 1 minute increment but i want seconds to be included to too. how to do it? is there a way to add seconds to timestamp? can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

ExtJs has a very rich Date function. To get the seconds timestamp:

```
var seconds = (new Date()).format('U');
```